# Fail install mongodb on Centos 7 with Package error

Tags: php, mongodb, centos7, yum

I try to install mongodb to Centos 7 server with PHP. I follow the install guide from https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

But `sudo pecl install mongodb` show error message:

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading mongodb-1.8.1.tgz ...
Starting to download mongodb-1.8.1.tgz (1,292,453 bytes)
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done: 1,292,453 bytes
586 source files, building
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

As the error message recommded, I install `php-devel package` by

```
yum install php-devel
```

But I got a lot of Dependency error:

```
Error: Package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
           Installed: libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64 (installed)
               libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-16.el7
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.1
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
Error: Package: libcom_err-devel-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-10.el7
           Installed: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (installed)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Available: libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-10.el7
Error: Package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
           Installed: libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64 (installed)
               libstdc++ = 4.8.2-16.el7_5
               libstdc++ = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libstdc++ = 4.8.5-16.el7
               libstdc++ = 4.8.2-16.el7
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libstdc++ = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.1
               libstdc++ = 4.8.2-16.el7_4
           Available: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libstdc++ = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
               libstdc++ = 4.8.2-16.el7_4
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Installed: glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Installed: glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7
           Available: glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               glibc = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
Error: Package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
           Requires: libgomp = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
           Installed: libgomp-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64 (installed)
               libgomp = 4.8.2-16.el7_5
               libgomp = 4.8.5-28.el7_5.1
           Available: libgomp-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libgomp = 4.8.5-16.el7
               libgomp = 4.8.2-16.el7
           Available: libgomp-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libgomp = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.1
               libgomp = 4.8.2-16.el7_4
           Available: libgomp-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-updates)
               libgomp = 4.8.5-16.el7_4.2
               libgomp = 4.8.2-16.el7_4
Error: Package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-8.el7
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-8.el7
Error: Package: libkadm5-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
           Installed: krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
           Available: krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
Error: Package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
           Installed: krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
           Available: krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
Error: Package: libsepol-devel-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: libsepol(x86-64) = 2.5-6.el7
           Installed: libsepol-2.5-8.1.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libsepol(x86-64) = 2.5-8.1.el7
           Available: libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libsepol(x86-64) = 2.5-6.el7
Error: Package: libselinux-devel-2.5-11.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
           Requires: libselinux(x86-64) = 2.5-11.el7
           Installed: libselinux-2.5-12.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libselinux(x86-64) = 2.5-12.el7
           Available: libselinux-2.5-11.el7.x86_64 (ultra-centos-7.4-base)
               libselinux(x86-64) = 2.5-11.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Below are the server details, any solution?

> yum repolist

```
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: download.nus.edu.sg
 * remi-php73: mirrors.thzhost.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.thzhost.com
repo id                                                                    repo name                                                                                               status
MongoDB/7/x86_64                                                           MongoDB Repository                                                                                          62
*epel/x86_64                                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                          13,463
ius/x86_64                                                                 IUS for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                        486
mongodb-org-3.4/7                                                          MongoDB Repository                                                                                         125
nodesource/x86_64                                                          Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                           106
remi-php73                                                                 Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                              384
remi-safe                                                                  Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                               4,006
ultra-centos-7.4-base                                                      UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Base                                                                             7,407
ultra-centos-7.4-extras                                                    UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Extras                                                                             401
ultra-centos-7.4-updates                                                   UltraServe CentOS-7.4 - Updates                                                                          1,836
ultra-centos-7.x-newrelic-monitoring                                       UltraServe CentOS-7.x - New Relic Infrastructure Monitoring Agent                                           10
ultra-centos-7.x-ultrarepo                                                 UltraServe CentOS-7.x - UltraServe Repo Packages                                                            50
repolist: 28,336
```

> rpm -q centos-release

```
centos-release-7-5.1804.el7.centos.2.x86_64
```

> php --version

```
PHP 7.3.23 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2020 08:33:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.23, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remi-php73                                                                 Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                              384

Looks like you are using my repository which provides [most extensions](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status)

So, instead of trying to build it from sources, I recommend to simply use the available RPMs

```
yum install php-pecl-mongodb
```

Or if you use the Software Collections

```
yum install php73-pecl-mongodb
```

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

BTW, the installation issue seems related to **ultra-centos-7.4-base** (don't even know what is this) as you have installed packages from 7.5

Comment: Thank you very much! The command works, but it's weird that `php -i | grep mongo` return nothing. Finally, I build the MongoDB PHP Driver from source (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php). Then add `extension = mongodb.so;` on `/etc/opt/remi/php73{your_php_version}/php.ini`, now I can also install `composer require mongodb/mongodb`

Comment: If you use "php73-php*" packages you need "php73-php-pecl-mongodb", as explained by the wizard, also read the FAQ https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Answer (score 1):

Seem the **ultra-centos-7.4-base** come with AWS EC2 server.

To people who face the same dependency issue, you may consider change the repos source by:

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo http://wiki.docking.org/index.php/CentOS_7_Base.repo
sed -i  's/$releasever/7/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Double check you repo:

```
yum repolist
```

Then you should able to run `yum install php-devel`

Comment: I've searched high and low for a solution to the dependency hell that I was in about mismatching versions of GCC. This solution (though I did have to manually copy and paste the repo contents linked to above to avoid all the HTML surrounding it) worked! Thank you Sam Chu!